# vim search and replace

Tags: regex, vim, special-characters

How do I use vim's search and replace (i.e :s) to replace the string: 
'''($circleSize)'''
with:
'''$circleSize'''

Also I cant just replace '''(''' and ''')''' with nothing, or delete them cause they arent the only ones on the code plus those that i do want to remove are spread amongs the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command to substitute:

```
:%s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
:%s/\v(\()(\$circleSize)(\))/\2/g

\v ............. very magic
() ............. non-scaped parenthesis represents regex groups
\2 ............. matches de second group
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please expand upon the "magic"?
Is it an inside joke or term which I don't get or is it just complex and I should research it on my own?
tytyty

Comment: If you type on your vim `:h \v` you will see that it is an actual feature of vim, it allows you to use regular regex expressions more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\zs` and `\ze` to make it easier to read:

```
s/\zs(\(\$circleSize\))\ze/\1/
```

Or repeat the string without using the capture group:

```
s/\zs(\$circleSize)\ze/$circleSize/
```

You can make it with the flag `g` or `:%s/....`, depending on your real text.